# How to display images in a Recycler View (Grid Layout)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

How to display all images in drawable res folder in a Recycler View (Grid Layout)? What if there are hundereds of them?

I tried the regular method and it worked but I had only 5 images then. How to do the same for 100 images, it is a lot of work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It'd be super helpful if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, so we can help you with your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
```

and to view image you have to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) in your recycler adapter

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a drawbles array that would store all your images, then using a loop to display all of them.

```
Drawble [] drawables = new Drawable[]{ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.digit00),ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.digit01),ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.digit02));
```

You can also use a loop to print out what you will put in the drawable array, so you can save on typing.

For example create a loop that prints '***ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.digit' + int')***' to the logcat (the **int** is an int that will be incremented each time, this is why i said to name your drawables with a number at the end, like digit00 - digit99). Then you can just copy all that into your real code.